# How to add two form_class's in FormMixin?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-generic-views

So i've already done my `register()` form, which is working fine. I'm now trying to do my `login()` form, however the fields (`username` and `password`) are not showing up because i'm unable to add 2 values to form_class in `BoxesView()`. There is already a value in form_class for the register form, so I need to add another. To be honest, i'm not entirely sure how form_class is working here, or if it's possible to add another one so if someone could explain that would be great. Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView, FormMixin):
    template_name = 'polls.html'  # extends base.html
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data()

        question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        choice = Choice.objects.all()
        context['question_list'] = question_list
        context['choice'] = choice

        q_list = []
        returned_list = []

        for i in question_list:
            q_list.append(i)

        for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
            name = resolve(self.request.path_info).url_name
            if b == name:
                category = a

        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')
        if search:
            posts = posts.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=search) |
                Q(content__icontains=search)
            )
        else:
            posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')

        context['posts'] = posts

        total = 0
        for post in posts:
            returned_list.append(post)
            total += 1
            if total == 4:
                total = 0
                for i in q_list:
                    returned_list.append(i)
                    q_list.remove(i)
                    break

        paginator = Paginator(returned_list, 14)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            lst = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            lst = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            lst = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['lst'] = lst

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        pass


def register(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return redirect('/')


def user_login(request):
    form_login = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
    if form_login.is_valid():
        username = form_login.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form_login.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
    else:
        form_login = UserLoginForm()
    return redirect('/')
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'password'
        ]


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'confirm_password',
        ]
```

**base.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'user_login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="loginWrapper">
<div class="login">
    <div class="loginBox">
        {{ form_login.username }}
        {{ form_login.password }}
        <input type="submit" value="login" style="margin-left: 10px"/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'register' %}">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="registerWrapper">
<div class="register">
    <div class="registerBox">
        {{ form.errors }}
        {{ form.username|placeholder:"username" }}
        {{ form.email|placeholder:"email" }}
        {{ form.password|placeholder:"password" }}
        {{ form.confirm_password|placeholder:"confirm password" }}
        <input type="submit" value="register" />

    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know how `FormMixin` uses `form_class`, you can just read the code - hey, it's opensource you know.

So if you check `FormMixin`'s code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.4/django/views/generic/edit.py#L11), you find out that `form_class` is - surprise surprise - used to instanciate your form.

Now wrt/ your question, you mainly have two options:

1. ditch FormMixin (which is not designed to handle multiple forms) and implement what you need in your View class
2. ditch class-based views completely and write a good old view function

Don't get me wrong: class-based views are fine for quite a lot of stuff, but sometimes plain function-based views are just *way* simpler to write, read and maintain.